# asymptotic expansion of a series related to $\cosh(x)$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, closed-form, summation-method, poisson-summation-formula

Let the function 
$$
F(x)=\frac{\pi\sinh(x)}{x}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh\left[\frac{(2n+1)\pi^2}{2x}\right]}
$$
where $\cosh(x)=\lambda\geq1$. For $\lambda\to1$, i.e., $x\to0$, what's the asymptotic expansion of $F$? The expansion can be expressed via $\lambda$, e.g., $F\simeq 3\sqrt{\lambda-1}+\,\mathcal{O}((\lambda-1)^2)$ (NOTE: This is NOT the right answer, however).

**My naive solution**

To begin with, we have $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}=1$ and $x\simeq\sqrt{2(\lambda-1)}$, and 
$$
F(x)=\frac{2\pi\sinh(x)}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh\left[\frac{(2n+1)\pi^2}{2x}\right]}\\
\simeq4\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\frac{(2n+1)\pi^2}{2x}\right]\\
=4\pi\exp\left[-\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt{2(\lambda-1)}}\right]+\textrm{HIGH-ORDER}
$$

Comment: You mentioned the Poisson summation formula. What do you get using that $\frac{1}{\cosh}= \text{sech}$ is its own Fourier transform ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know to what order you want the asymptotic expansion, but finding it up to leading order is simple:

$$F(x)=\pi \frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = \pi \frac{x+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{x} = \pi\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\right) $$
Further, as you mentioned correctly
$$ \cosh(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2) =\lambda \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{2(\lambda-1)}+ o(\sqrt{\lambda-1}).$$

Simply combining these two expressions gives the leading order term of the asymptotic expansion of $F$:
$$ F(x) = \frac{\pi}{3}\left(2+\lambda+o(\lambda-1)\right).$$

The relative error for $x=0.5$ is about $\frac{|F(x)-\frac{\pi}{3}(2+\lambda)|}{F(x)}\approx 4\%$, for $x=0.1$ it is $0.1\%$.